# How to make request directly to device in other network PHP

Tags: php, web-services, web, ip, router

How can I make GET request directly to device in other network with PHP? Like if I know it's LAN IP is 192.168.1.29 and Global IP is 10.2.4.195. I tried Port Forwarding it works but some routers don't have Forwarding functionality. So is there any way to directly make request to device without Port Forwarding?

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to do rather than how you want to do it. It is not possible to connect to another device without port forwarding (either static or UPnP). A commonly used alternative to to establish a connection in reverse (the device connects to your server, rather than your server connecting to the device).

Comment: @Chris I have AVR device that is connected to internet over ENC28J60 module. But my router doesn't have function to port forward. My device just makes request once when turning on and it can't read answer of request it sends.

Comment: This is not generally possible.

Comment: Is there something that I can do or no way?

Comment: @Teymur_PC It is very unlikely your router doesn't support port forwarding. What router do you have?

Comment: It isn't actual router it is connected to usb port and I bridge it over LAN to my device from my PC.

Comment: If you just want to test making requests locally I'd recommend Postman, a very handy tool.

Comment: I can locally make request. I want to make request over anoher network

Comment: @Teymur_PC I'm not sure how this USB device shows up on the host computer, but if you bridge the networks directly rather than NATing them the device should be visible on your internal network.

Comment: @Chris It is visible on my internal network. I need to make request from site on other network.

Comment: @Teymur_PC So surely you can just use port forwarding on your router to expose a port on that device to the internet and then you can make a request from anywhere?

Comment: I can do it with normal router but can't do it on that device.

Comment: @Teymur_PC I'm not sure I understand. If your device is visible on your internal network and the internal network is connected to the external network via a normal router then it should be possible to just port forward directly from the external network to the device with your normal router.

Comment: That USB device is connected to PC and it is connected to internet over satelites.